# postalCode got (null) in iOS Google Maps SDK reverse geocoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I cannot convince why postalCode got (null) in iOS Google Maps SDK. Below is my code.

```
[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {
                NSLog(@"reverse geocoding results:");
                for(GMSAddress* addressObj in [response results])
                {
                    NSLog(@"coordinate.latitude=%f", addressObj.coordinate.latitude);
                    NSLog(@"coordinate.longitude=%f", addressObj.coordinate.longitude);
                    NSLog(@"thoroughfare=%@", addressObj.thoroughfare);
                    NSLog(@"locality=%@", addressObj.locality);
                    NSLog(@"subLocality=%@", addressObj.subLocality);
                    NSLog(@"administrativeArea=%@", addressObj.administrativeArea);
                    NSLog(@"postalCode=%@", addressObj.postalCode);
                    NSLog(@"country=%@", addressObj.country);
                    NSLog(@"lines=%@", addressObj.lines);

                }
            }];
```

Here is result of above coding.

```
2015-12-21 17:36:58.138 coordinate.latitude=51.509980
2015-12-21 17:36:58.138 coordinate.longitude=-0.133700
2015-12-21 17:36:58.138 thoroughfare=(null)
2015-12-21 17:36:58.138 locality=London
2015-12-21 17:36:58.138 subLocality=(null)
2015-12-21 17:36:58.139 administrativeArea=(null)
2015-12-21 17:36:58.139 postalCode=(null)
2015-12-21 17:36:58.139 country=United Kingdom
2015-12-21 17:36:58.142 lines=(
    "",
    "London, UK"
)
```

Please help me how to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an engineer on the Google Maps SDK for iOS. At first glance, this looks like a bug. Could you please file an issue on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:IosSDK%20type:Defect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars)? This will help us track this issue and prioritize it against other issues. Please include the SDK version that you're using and the coordinate that you are trying to reverse geocode.

Answer (score 0):

Hello All i found solution please use this code

```
[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {
                NSLog(@"reverse geocoding results:");
                GMSAddress* addressObj = [response firstResult];

                    NSLog(@"coordinate.latitude=%f", addressObj.coordinate.latitude);
                    NSLog(@"coordinate.longitude=%f", addressObj.coordinate.longitude);
                    NSLog(@"thoroughfare=%@", addressObj.thoroughfare);
                    NSLog(@"locality=%@", addressObj.locality);
                    NSLog(@"subLocality=%@", addressObj.subLocality);
                    NSLog(@"administrativeArea=%@", addressObj.administrativeArea);
                    NSLog(@"postalCode=%@", addressObj.postalCode);
                    NSLog(@"country=%@", addressObj.country);
                    NSLog(@"lines=%@", addressObj.lines);


            }];
```